# Invalid API call as no apiproduct match found.

Tags: apigee

I have just started coding with APIgee I found this error can anyone help me with this

```
"faultstring":"Invalid API call as no apiproduct match found",

"errorcode":"keymanagement.service.InvalidAPICallAsNoApiProductMatchFound"
```

Comment: I had this error, after editing the resource paths and scopes and re-saving, it disappeared even when setting back to the original values. It seems to be a bit flaky in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure that your API bundle is associated with at least 1 API Product.

Comment: it is associated i have created a product and a developer app but still its giving me this.I am also using it in my API

Comment: I've only seen this error when an API proxy is not associated with a Product (that in turn, needs to be associated with an App).  You are seeing that Product also associated with the App for the respective client_id?

Answer (score 3):

Have you used the trace facility to figure out which policy is failing?

Most likely your API Key is not not associated with a product bundle.

Go to the "developer App": Dashboard / Developer Apps / 
And check that the product you are trying to access is indeed listed in the products list

Comment: Yes i have traced. my oauth policy is failing.after which i have my API key.if i remove the oauth policy the flow works but with the aouth policy it gives me an error..

Answer (score 1):

click on publish > products from menu bar, select product which is associated to your proxy. under "paths" make sure the path of your endpoint is listed if not click on edit pencil icon and add path and save

Answer (score 1):

Api key Approval at the time of creating product you selected manual select it automatically ,, your problem will be resolved

Answer (score -3):

If an oauth policy is added then trace session doesn't work... because you need to add a header which consists of access code which can be done in console. If you are new to Apigee then I would suggest you to go and watch the foundation training video especially Lesson 6 which explains about OAuth v.2.0 in detail.