# "title": "Invalid input.", "detail": "An invalid field type was passed in.",

Tags: node.js, typescript, klaviyo

**{
"statusCode": 400,
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"id": "400db520-d02b-4d74-8f74-198def822116",
"status": 400,
"code": "invalid",
"title": "Invalid input.",
"detail": "An invalid field type was passed in.",
"source": {
"pointer": "/data"
},
"meta": {}
}
]
}
}

below as my payload
{
"data": {
"type": "profile-subscription-bulk-create-job",
"attributes": {
"custom_source": "Marketing Event",
"profiles": {
"data": [
{
"type": "profile",
"attributes": {
"email": "abc@gmail.com",
"phone_number": "+0000000000",
"subscriptions": {
"email": {
"marketing": {
"consent": "SUBSCRIBED"
}
},
"sms": {
"marketing": {
"consent": "SUBSCRIBED"
}
}
}
}
}
]
}
},
"relationships": {
"list": {
"data": {
"type": "list",
"id": "XXXXX"
}
}
}
}
}

It's above payload perfectly working on Api call but my codebase it doesn't work alternatively occured above top apge mentioned error

solution for above issue

Comment: This is klaviyo profile Api create profile subscribes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035609/invalid-api-call-as-no-apiproduct-match-found